# How to vectorize a list of words python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I am trying to use the CountVectorizer module with Sci-kit Learn. From what I read, it seems like it can be used on a list of sentences, like:

['This is the first document.','This is the second second document.','And the third one.', 'Is this the first document?']

However, is there a way to vectorize a collection of words in list form, such as [['this', 'is', 'text', 'document', 'to', 'analyze'], ['and', 'this', 'is', 'the', 'second'],['and', 'this', 'and', 'that', 'are', 'third']?

I am trying to convert each list to a sentence using `' '.join(wordList)`, but I am getting an error:

> TypeError: sequence item 13329: expected string or Unicode, generator
>   found

when I try to run:

```
vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=50)
ratings = vectorizer.fit_transform([' '.join(wordList)])
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to do this:

```
counts = vectorizer.fit_transform(wordList)  # sparse matrix with columns corresponding to words
words = vectorizer.get_feature_names()  # array with words corresponding to columns
```

Finally, to get `[['this', 'is', 'text', 'document', 'to', 'analyze']]`

```
sample_idx = 1
sample_words = [words[i] for i, count in 
                enumerate(counts.toarray()[sample_idx]) if count > 0]
```